# Sending only one mail for all attachments C# "Light switch 2011"?

Tags: c#, email, email-attachments, visual-studio-lightswitch

I managed to develop a code which enable me to send a mail for each selected line in my table. The problem is it send to me for each line  a separate E-mail "each line has a PDF ". I just want to send only one mail for all PDFs attachments.

```
enter code here
foreach (vw_CustLedgerEntryItem1 item in _ItemsList.SelectedItems)
        {
            //you would normally process each row 
            //but here we're just concatenating the properties as 
            //proof that we are processing the selected rows 
            //vw_CustLedgerEntryItem1 entryItem = this.vw_CustLedgerEntry.SelectedItem;
            InvSendbyMailRequestBody reqBody = new InvSendbyMailRequestBody(
                  item.Document_No_
                , item.Report_Type
                , "DynNavHRS"
                , ""
                , this.Application.User.Name.Replace(@"HRS\", "") + "@hrs.com" // HRS001
                , "Document"
                , false
                , false
                , this.vw_CustomerItem.ISO_Code                         // Change 7.8.2014 Bug in Email body text sprache
                , this.vw_CustomerItem.Salesperson_E_mail               // Change 7.8.2014 Bug in Send E-mail
                , item.Customer_No_.ToString()
                , false
                , ""
                , ""
                , "XYZ"
                , false);

            InvSendbyMailRequest req = new InvSendbyMailRequest(reqBody);
            HRSReportServiceSoapClient wsHRS = new HRSReportServiceSoapClient();
            wsHRS.InvSendbyMailAsync(req);
        }

        this.ShowMessageBox("Your email was successfully sent");
    }
```

How can I have only one Email with all attachment instead of 2 mails?
Please help.

Thanks alot,
Zayed

Comment: I don't really understand from your code how attachments are involved. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Its a little bit complicated. I am calling a web service which call my SSRS reporting services in order to create for me the PDFs then I add them to my mail.  I talked with my manager "Leader developer"  and he said with this method it wont be possible. Coz each iteration of this method is like a stream and I just cannot add such iteration together :(